# What statistical analysis to use for a diary study?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, interaction, multilevel-analysis, mediation, methodology

I was wondering which statistical strategy/technique is best for my research, which is a diary study. I have developed a theoretical framework, a mediated moderation model see figure below. All variables are measured by multiple dimensions, except for the moderator variable (is it ok to see these variables as latent variables then?). Thanks in advance!

[image: Mediated moderation model]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Can you provide more information on how your data was collected and what your research hypothesis is?

Comment: Data is collected by a diary survey of 5 working days, with an experimental and control group (which is the moderator variable). Hypotheses are all arrows/relations of the framework, which are hypothesized to be positive. Thus, independent variable positively influences the variables which are connected etcetera. For the moderator variable I expect that the relations will be stronger for the experimental group.